# image from ALAsset in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have images that returned from the camera by the ALAssetsLibrary. Now, I want to display it in a `UIImageView`. I tried this code, but it shows some errors:

```
var assets : ALAsset = photoArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as ALAsset

cell.cameraOutlet.image = UIImage(CGImage: assets.thumbnail()) as UIImage // Showing error - Missing argument for parameter 'inBundle' in call
```

after that, I tried this code:

```
var assets : ALAsset = (photoArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as ALAsset)
 var imageRef : CGImageRef = assets.thumbnail() as CGImageRef // showing error - Unmanaged<CGImage>, is not convertible to CGImageRef
 cell.cameraOutlet.image = UIImage(CGImage: assets.thumbnail()) as UIImage // Showing error - Missing argument for parameter 'inBundle' in call
```

I want to display the image, how can I do this?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
self.photoLibrary.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupType(ALAssetsGroupAlbum),
    usingBlock: {

        (group: ALAssetsGroup!, stop: UnsafePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        if group != nil {
            group.enumerateAssetsUsingBlock({
                (asset: ALAsset!, index: Int, stop: UnsafePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in

                if asset != nil
                {
                    if asset.valueForProperty(ALAssetPropertyType).isEqualToString(ALAssetTypePhoto)
                    {
                        self.photoArray.addObject(asset)
                    }
                }
                })
        }
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    },
    failureBlock: {
        (myerror: NSError!) -> Void in
        println("error occurred: \(myerror.localizedDescription)")
    })
    })

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
        return photoArray.count
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {
    let cell  : CameraCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Camera", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CameraCollectionViewCell

        var asset : ALAsset = photoArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as ALAsset
        cell.cameraOutlet.image = UIImage(CGImage: asset.thumbnail().takeUnretainedValue()) as UIImage
        return cell
    }
```

The output shows only one image for a 100 time I think. Whats the problem with this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `thumbnail()` function returns `Unmanaged<CGImage>`. As explained in
[Working with Cocoa Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html), you have to  convert the unmanaged object to a memory managed object with `takeUnretainedValue()` or `takeRetainedValue()`.
In this case

```
cell.cameraOutlet.image = UIImage(CGImage: asset.thumbnail().takeUnretainedValue())
```

because `thumbnail()` returns an unretained object (is does not have "create" or "copy"
in its name).

**Swift 3:**

```
cell.cameraOutlet.image = UIImage(cgImage: asset.thumbnail().takeUnretainedValue())
```

(However, the Asset Library framework is deprecated as of iOS 9
and the Photos framework should be used instead.)

Comment: i have one more doubt

Comment: Hi @Martin, you explained that the function name does not include "create" or "copy" in it's name, so we can infer that the returned object is unretained. I was wondering if you might be able to point me to any documentation that clarifies this further? Or maybe an example of a function where I should use `takeRetainedValue()` instead? Thanks!

Comment: @nathan.f77: It is documented in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html. Here is an example where you would use takeRetainedValue(): http://stackoverflow.com/a/26594980/1187415

Comment: po assetSuper.thumbnail().takeUnretainedValue()
<CGImage 0x7fd9bb47ec90>

Answer (score 0):

```
i dislay image use this way:

let assetslibrary = ZZALAssetsLibrary()
        assetslibrary.asset(for: imgUrl,
        resultBlock: { [weak self](mALAsset) in
            if (mALAsset == nil) {
                return
            }
            //[UIImage imageWithCGImage:resolutionRef scale:1.0f orientation:(UIImageOrientation)representation.orientation];
            if let mCGImageVal = mALAsset?.defaultRepresentation().fullScreenImage().takeUnretainedValue() {
                self?.imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: mCGImageVal)
            }
        },
        failureBlock: { (mError) in
            print("ZZPhotoBrowserCell Photo from asset library error: ",mError ?? "unkown")
        })
```