# Comparing Unmanaged<AnyObject> to nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1

The code is copied from this blog post: http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/06/21/example-ios-keychain-swift-save-query/

I used to have this code:

```
// Search for the keychain items
let status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery, &dataTypeRef)

// The following line crashes with an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS if dataTypeRef is nil
var opaque = dataTypeRef!.toOpaque()
```

When I run the above using a new account value in the keychain query the `dataTypeRef` will be `nil` which leads to an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`.

I tried to circumvent this by checking if `dataTypeRef` is `nil` like this:

```
var opaque = COpaquePointer.null()
if (dataTypeRef != nil) {
    opaque = dataTypeRef!.toOpaque()    // This line should not be executed.
}
```

While the debugger shows that `dataTypeRef` is `nil` it will still enter the if clause and crash.

Could anyone explain what is going on here? I do have experience in Objective-C but I can't figure out what's going on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the `toOpaque/fromOpaque` dances are no longer necessary, and you
can simply use optional binding. This can be combined with the cast to `NSData`
using optional chaining:

```
let status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery, &dataTypeRef)
if let retrievedData = dataTypeRef?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSData {
    contentsOfKeychain = NSString(data: retrievedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
```

Note also that `takeRetainedValue()` is the correct choice here because you "own"
the item returned by `SecItemCopyMatching` (it has "Copy" in its name).

But actually you should check the *return value* first:

```
let status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery, &dataTypeRef)
if status == errSecSuccess {
    if let retrievedData = dataTypeRef?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSData {
        contentsOfKeychain = NSString(data: retrievedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
}
```

Comment: While I understand the meaning of `if let retrievedData = dataTypeRef?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSData` I think it is pretty ugly. Is there a reason not to use `let retrievedData = dataTypeRef?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSData` followed by `if nil != retrievedData`?

Comment: @Paul: `if let retrievedData = ...` is an "optional binding", so that `retrievedData` contains the *unwrapped* variable if the if-block is executed. `let retrievedData = ...; if nil != retrievedData { ... }` is also possible, but then `retrievedData` is an *optional* which still has to be unwrapped with `!`: `contentsOfKeychain = NSString(data: retrievedData!, ...)`. That's why I prefer the first method but both work.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I prefer my version just for the sake of legibility.